# How can I control several columns at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table and I want to control the selection with the `DATE_FORM` variable.

Why does my T-SQL code not work? Does someone have an idea?

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3VQB.png)

```
-- @DATE_FORM = 1 select a particular INFO-DATE INTERVALL
-- @DATE_FORM = 2 select a particular ORDER-DATE INTERVALL
-- @DATE_FORM = 3 select a particular SHIPPING INTERVALL

DECLARE @DATE_FORM int = 3,
        @FROM smalldatetime  = '2022-10-05 00:00:00',
        @UNTIL smalldatetime = '2022-10-06 00:00:00';

SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2019].[dbo].[Table_2]
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 1 THEN INFO_DATE 
            WHEN @DATE_FORM = 2 THEN ORDER_DATE END) BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL
  AND ((CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 3 THEN SHIPPING_DATE_START END) BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL
        AND (CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 3 THEN SHIPPING_DATE_END END) BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL)
```

Comment: Aside; Your query isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Well, it _might_ be if it is always [recompiled](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/) before execution and the query optimizer is having a really good day. A `union all` of three queries, one for each value of `@DATE_FORM`, might provide better performance. Or using `if` to execute a query specific to the `@DATE_FORM` value. The _actual execution plan_ would help you choose a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your cases doesn't allow your conditions to ever be met.
For instance, let's say `@Date_Form = 3`, what will happen to this condition?:

```
(CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 1 THEN INFO_DATE 
      WHEN @DATE_FORM = 2 THEN ORDER_DATE 
   END) between @FROM and @UNTIL
```

Since `@DATE_FORM = 3` is not handled in the `Case` it would bascially result in:

```
null between @From AND @UNTIL
```

which will result in false..
I would (for simplicity) remove the cases completely:

```
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2019].[dbo].[Table_2]
WHERE (@DATE_FORM = 1 
      AND INFO_DATE BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL)
OR    (@DATE_FORM = 2 
      AND ORDER_DATE BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL)
OR    (@DATE_FORM = 3 
       AND SHIPPING_DATE_START BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL 
       AND SHIPPING_DATE_END BETWEEN @FROM AND @UNTIL)
```

Comment: Great job. It help me a lot. But you have still an Error inside. This is probably right see above in your post

Comment: Okey, nice! :) oh, what was the error?

Comment: You right. Your code seems to deliver the right results. Great.

Answer (score 1):

The first condition:

```
AND (CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 1 THEN INFO_DATE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 2   THEN ORDER_DATE END) between @FROM and @UNTIL`
```

When `@DATE_FORM` is `3` that will just be `AND NULL between @FROM and @UNTIL` which will always be `FALSE`.

Since that is always `FALSE` when `@Date_Form = 3` then you likely want to switch your `AND` to an `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2019].[dbo].[Table_2]
WHERE 
   (CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 1   THEN INFO_DATE 
            WHEN @DATE_FORM = 2   THEN ORDER_DATE END) between @FROM and @UNTIL
  OR ( 
        (CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 3 THEN SHIPPING_DATE_START END) between @FROM and @UNTIL
        AND (CASE WHEN @DATE_FORM = 3 THEN SHIPPING_DATE_END END) between @FROM and @UNTIL
     )
```

Comment: Great code. It delivers. I need to invest some time to understand it. I am not a pro like you